# How can I use RxJS-jQuery with browserify's require

Tags: jquery, browserify, rxjs

I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in my app. I bundle all my source files with [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Thus, I import the [npm version of jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery):

```
const $ = require('jQuery');
```

I also use [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) and like to use the [jQuery Bindings for the Reactive Extensions for JavaScript](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery), but if I `require('rxjs-jquery')` I only get the `Rx` object. How can I require the jQuery object to be able to use this example:

```
function searchWikipedia(term) {
    return $.ajaxAsObservable({
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
        data: { action: 'opensearch',
                search: term,
                format: 'json' }
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}
```

Comment: you can have more than one `require`s. So `const $ = require('jQuery'); const rxJq = require('rxjs-jquery');`

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, that was too obvious to figure it out by myself  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one `require`.

```
const $ = require('jQuery');
const rxJq = require('rxjs-jquery');
```